# A space obtained by $S^3$ by removing a Hopf link

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

If we remove a [Hopf link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_link) from $3$-dimensional sphere $S^3$, can we obtain a space homotopy equivalent to (or deformation retract to) an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics))?

If the answer yes, can we write it explicitly?

**EDIT:** Let $H^+$ denote the positive Hopf link. If we remove $H^+$ from $S^3$, we obtain a Milnor fibration $\pi_+: S^3-H^+ \to S^1$ given by the rule $(r_1,\theta_1,r_2,\theta_2) \to \theta_1+\theta_2$, see [Etnyre](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~etnyre/preprints/papers/oblec.pdf)'s note. This gives an open book decomposition of $S^3$ with a page annulus.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the fundamental group of $ S^3 $ minus two linked circles is $ \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} $ and hence it cannot retract to an annulus. It deformation retracts to a torus though.

Comment: I guess, your argument is probably true for $\mathbb{IR}^3$ instead of $S^3$.

Comment: Working in $\Bbb R^3$ won't change the fundamental group of the answer. But it should be said that the calculation given is *for the Hopf link*, not an arbitrary pair of linked unknots.

Comment: Are you sure? I think that if we remove Hopf link from $S^3$, then we have to obtain infinitely many ($S^1$  times) annulus due to Milnor's fibration theorem.

Comment: You should give more detail as to why you think it should be an annulus. Also it wouldn't hurt to be more clear as to what link it is (there are many ways to link unknots which is what Mike is saying). What do you think the fundamental group of $S^3$ minus an unknot is?

Comment: I edited the post to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hopf link is a torus link, it's complement (as the one of any algebraic link) fibers over the circle with fiber a minimal genus Seifert surface. More explicitly $S^3 \setminus \nu (L)$ is diffeomorphic to $A\times [0,1]/\sim$, where $A=S^1 \times [0,1]$ denotes the annulus, and $\sim$  the equivalence relation identifying $(x,1) \sim (\tau_\gamma(x), 0)$ where $\tau_\gamma:A \to A$ denotes a Dhen twist along $\gamma= S^1 \times \{1/2\}$. Thus $S^3 \setminus \nu (L)$ is homotopic equivalent to the two-torus $S^1 \times S^1$

In general $S^3 \setminus \nu (K_{p,q})$, where $K_{p,q}$ denotes the $(p,q)$ torus knot, is homotopic equivalent to $F_g \times S^1$ where $F_g$ denotes a bouquet of $g=(p-1) (q-1)$ circles.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a couple of confusions here.

The Hopf fibration is a presentation of $S^3$ as an (oriented) circle bundle over $S^2$. In particular, when you delete the north and south pole, you have a circle bundle over $\Bbb R \times S^1$; projecting once more to the circle factor, you have an annulus bundle over $S^1$. This is the open book decomposition you cite.

You can *not* conclude from this that the total space is homotopy equivalent to a generic fiber of this bundle: it's simply not true! You're ignoring the homotopy type of the base. Instead, what you are able to actually say is that the total space is homotopy equivalent to a circle bundle over $S^1$ (start with the circle bundle over $S^1 \times \Bbb R$, and then crush the $\Bbb R$ factor to a point). In fact, the whole bundle over $S^1 \times \Bbb R$ is trivial (exercise: write down a global trivialization), and hence $S^3 \setminus H \cong S^1 \times \Bbb R \times S^1$. As a corollary, you find the description in one of the comments that $\pi_1(S^3 \setminus H) = \pi_1 T^2 = \Bbb Z^2$.

As a brief comment on the difference between $S^3$ and $\Bbb R^3$, here are a few general principles. First, deleting a set of codimension larger than $2$ does not change the fundamental group. Second, you can explicitly understand the homotopy type of $\Bbb R^3 \setminus L$ given that of $S^3 \setminus L$: in fact, we have a homotopy equivalence $$\Bbb R^3 \setminus L \simeq (S^3 \setminus L) \vee S^2.$$ (This is a general fact: if $M$ is a noncompact $n$-manifold, then $M \setminus \{pt\} \simeq M \vee S^{n-1}$. Argue by showing that $M$ deformation retracts onto an $(n-1)$-dimensional subcomplex, but even better, that it deformation retracts onto something of the form $M' \vee B^n$, where $M'$ is a subcomplex of dimension $(n-1)$; then puncturing in the interior of $B^n$, we obtain a deformation retraction onto $M' \vee S^{n-1}.$)

Comment: Your claim about $\pi_1 (S^3 \setminus H)$ violates the Theorem 6.5 of J. Milnor's Singular Points of Complex Hypersurfaces.

Comment: It most certainly does not! It is the exact same answer the other answer gives. I'll look at your reference to try to understand the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong.

Comment: The last paragraph of Alfieri makes sense everything.